# Regex match entire words only

Tags: regex, word-boundary

I have a regex expression that I'm using to find all the words in a given block of content, case insensitive, that are contained in a glossary stored in a database. Here's my pattern:

```
/($word)/i
```

The problem is, if I use `/(Foo)/i` then words like `Food` get matched.  There needs to be whitespace or a word boundary on both sides of the word.

How can I modify my expression to match only the word `Foo` when it is a word at the beginning, middle, or end of a sentence?

Comment: Most of the answers do not address hyphenated words.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

Use word boundaries:

```
/\b($word)\b/i
```

Or if you're searching for "S.P.E.C.T.R.E." like in Sinan Ünür's example:

```
/(?:\W|^)(\Q$word\E)(?:\W|$)/i
```

Comment: I was just typing up the long-hand version of this answer when you posted.  :)

Comment: @RichardSimoes `\b(<|>=)\b` doesn't match `>=`

Comment: @RichardSimoes and `\b[-|+][0-9]+\b` match `+10` in `43E+10`. Both I don't want.

Comment: what if i want to search word which is not appended or does not contained in any other word. then this logic won't work

Comment: How would someone get the mathematical comparison operators >= and <=?

Comment: upvoted! what is the difference between \bword\b and \b(word)\b i am getting difference results hence asking 1st would also match 'someword' second doesnt

Comment: Richard Simões, @Aaron this regex doesn't work with hyphenated words

Comment: simpler way for the last case, nest `()`:  `/(\b(regular|words)\b|a\.m\.|\p\.m\.|a\.i\.)/`  basically, keep the `\b` around the words that should be avoided when in between words, and don't use it on words that either a) do not work with `\b` such as words with `.` or b) that are unique enough or already composite words with space, hyphen, etc.

Answer (score 86):

### To match any whole word you would use the pattern `(\w+)`

Assuming you are using PCRE or something similar:

[image]

Above screenshot taken from this live example:
https://regex101.com/r/FGheKd/1

### Matching any whole word on the commandline with `(\w+)`

I'll be using the [phpsh interactive shell](http://www.phpsh.org/) on [Ubuntu 12.10](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/) to demonstrate the [PCRE regex engine](https://www.php.net/pcre) through the method known as [preg_match](https://www.php.net/preg_match)

Start phpsh, put some content into a variable, match on word.

```
el@apollo:~/foo$ phpsh

php> $content1 = 'badger'
php> $content2 = '1234'
php> $content3 = '$%^&'

php> echo preg_match('(\w+)', $content1);
1

php> echo preg_match('(\w+)', $content2);
1

php> echo preg_match('(\w+)', $content3);
0
```

The preg_match method used the PCRE engine within the PHP language to analyze variables: `$content1`, `$content2` and `$content3` with the `(\w)+` pattern.

$content1 and $content2 contain at least one word, $content3 does not.

### Match a number of literal words on the commandline with `(dart|fart)`

```
el@apollo:~/foo$ phpsh

php> $gun1 = 'dart gun';
php> $gun2 = 'fart gun';
php> $gun3 = 'farty gun';
php> $gun4 = 'unicorn gun';

php> echo preg_match('(dart|fart)', $gun1);
1

php> echo preg_match('(dart|fart)', $gun2);
1

php> echo preg_match('(dart|fart)', $gun3);
1

php> echo preg_match('(dart|fart)', $gun4);
0
```

variables gun1 and gun2 contain the string dart or fart.  gun4 does not.  However it may be a problem that looking for word `fart` matches `farty`.  To fix this, enforce word boundaries in regex.

### Match literal words on the commandline with word boundaries.

```
el@apollo:~/foo$ phpsh

php> $gun1 = 'dart gun';
php> $gun2 = 'fart gun';
php> $gun3 = 'farty gun';
php> $gun4 = 'unicorn gun';

php> echo preg_match('(\bdart\b|\bfart\b)', $gun1);
1

php> echo preg_match('(\bdart\b|\bfart\b)', $gun2);
1

php> echo preg_match('(\bdart\b|\bfart\b)', $gun3);
0

php> echo preg_match('(\bdart\b|\bfart\b)', $gun4);
0
```

So it's the same as the previous example except that the word `fart` with a `\b` word boundary does not exist in the content: `farty`.

Comment: a.m., p.m. ain't words?

Answer (score 11):

Using `\b` can yield surprising results. You would be better off figuring out what separates a word from its definition and incorporating that information into your pattern.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use re 'debug';

my $str = 'S.P.E.C.T.R.E. (Special Executive for Counter-intelligence,
Terrorism, Revenge and Extortion) is a fictional global terrorist
organisation';

my $word = 'S.P.E.C.T.R.E.';

if ( $str =~ /\b(\Q$word\E)\b/ ) {
    print $1, "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Compiling REx "\b(S\.P\.E\.C\.T\.R\.E\.)\b"
Final program:
   1: BOUND (2)
   2: OPEN1 (4)
   4:   EXACT  (9)
   9: CLOSE1 (11)
  11: BOUND (12)
  12: END (0)
anchored "S.P.E.C.T.R.E." at 0 (checking anchored) stclass BOUND minlen 14
Guessing start of match in sv for REx "\b(S\.P\.E\.C\.T\.R\.E\.)\b" against "S.P
.E.C.T.R.E. (Special Executive for Counter-intelligence,"...
Found anchored substr "S.P.E.C.T.R.E." at offset 0...
start_shift: 0 check_at: 0 s: 0 endpos: 1
Does not contradict STCLASS...
Guessed: match at offset 0
Matching REx "\b(S\.P\.E\.C\.T\.R\.E\.)\b" against "S.P.E.C.T.R.E. (Special Exec
utive for Counter-intelligence,"...
   0           |  1:BOUND(2)
   0           |  2:OPEN1(4)
   0           |  4:EXACT (9)
  14      |  9:CLOSE1(11)
  14      | 11:BOUND(12)
                                  failed...
Match failed
Freeing REx: "\b(S\.P\.E\.C\.T\.R\.E\.)\b"
```

Comment: I think a word will typically be a \w word, but interesting point.

Answer (score 6):

For Those who want to validate an Enum in their code you can following the guide

In Regex World you can use `^` for starting a string and `$` to end it. Using them in combination with `|` could be what you want :

```
^(Male)$|^(Female)$
```

It will return true only for `Male` or `Female` case.

Comment: `^` and `$` match the beginning (respectively the end) of a line, therefore your example would match *only* if those are the only words in the line.

Comment: and this exactly what i want when i want to validate an enum! what is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing it in Notepad++

```
[\w]+
```

Would give you the entire word, and you can add parenthesis to get it as a group. Example: `conv1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=a), padding='valid', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(inputs)`. I would like to move `LeakyReLU` into its own line as a comment, and replace the current activation. In notepad++ this can be done using the follow find command:

```
([\w]+)( = .+)(LeakyReLU.alpha=a.)(.+)
```

and  the replace command becomes:

```
\1\2'relu'\4 \n    # \1 = LeakyReLU\(alpha=a\)\(\1\)
```

The spaces is to keep the right formatting in my code. :)

Answer (score 2):

use word boundaries \b,

The following (using four escapes) works in my environment: Mac, safari Version 10.0.3 (12602.4.8)

```
var myReg = new RegExp(‘\\\\b’+ variable + ‘\\\\b’, ‘g’)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all "words" in a string

`/([^\s]+)/g`

> Basically `^/s` means break on spaces (or match groups of non-spaces)
> Don't forget the `g` for Greedy

#### Try it:

`"Not the answer you're looking for? Browse other questions tagged regex word-boundary or ask your own question.".match(/([^\s]+)/g)`

→ (17) ['Not', 'the', 'answer', "you're", 'looking', 'for?', 'Browse', 'other', 'questions', 'tagged', 'regex', 'word-boundary', 'or', 'ask', 'your', 'own', 'question.']

Comment: If you disagree, explain and give a better solution

Comment: Punctuation isn't a word, obliviously!

Answer (score 0):

`/(\s|^)TheWord(\s|$)/`

```js
console.log(/(\s|^)TheWord(\s|$)/i.test(' TheWord '));
console.log(/(\s|^)TheWord(\s|$)/i.test(' TheWord'));
console.log(/(\s|^)TheWord(\s|$)/i.test('TheWord'));
console.log(/(\s|^)TheWord(\s|$)/i.test(' this is TheWord '));
console.log(/(\s|^)TheWord(\s|$)/i.test(' this is TheWord'));
console.log(/(\s|^)TheWord(\s|$)/i.test('this is TheWord'));
console.log(/(\s|^)TheWord(\s|$)/i.test(' anything '));
console.log(/(\s|^)TheWord(\s|$)/i.test(' anything'));
console.log(/(\s|^)TheWord(\s|$)/i.test('anything'));
console.log(/(\s|^)TheWord(\s|$)/i.test(' this is anything '));
console.log(/(\s|^)TheWord(\s|$)/i.test(' this is anything'));
console.log(/(\s|^)TheWord(\s|$)/i.test('this is anything'));
```