# preg_replace regex doesn't replace what it should

Tags: regex, preg-replace, preg-match-all

since hours I am on this problem:

```
// b) replace xls operation with fitting vars: E12 > var2233
preg_match_all('/[A-Z]{1,2}\d+/', $rowoperation["formulaxls"], $matches);
  $output = $rowoperation["formulaxls"];
  foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
    $result2 = $db->query("SELECT varid FROM variablen WHERE varimportedindex = '".$match."' AND projectid = $pid");
    $rowoperation = $result2->fetch_assoc();
    $output = preg_replace("#".$match."#", "var".$rowoperation['varid']."", $output);
    $output = preg_replace('#\,#', ";", $output);
    #$output = str_replace($match, "var".$rowoperation['varid']."", $output);
    #$output = str_replace(',', ";", $output);
  }
```

Output of matches seem to be ok. But the replacement is not. I always got strange replacements like "Avar30031=var3424 var3612=var3424 var3613=var3424 Avar30051=var3424". So i dont't understand, why it replaces "Avar" in between. The Numbers are then also not right.

Is it possible, that it makes problem with a Excel cellindex A10 because of the "0"?

Thank you all experts...

Regards
Olaf

Comment: Looks like you could leverage `preg_replace_callback`.

Comment: Yes i know, but this is not the problem at the moment i think.

Comment: Try to replace `"#".$match."#"` with `"#\b".$match."\b#"`.

Comment: Can you provide some samples of `$output` in the first place?

Comment: WOW!!! It works with /b, but why. Thank you!

Comment: @OlafK.: read about word-boundaries. Note that now you can use `strtr` or `str_replace` for the comma.

Comment: I have tried to repro, and it is not that easy without input text. If you think the word boundaries is all you missed, I suggest closing the question as a duplicate of [*Regex match entire words only*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751301/regex-match-entire-words-only).