# Regex Grouping and extraction of particular group based on regex look behind

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I want to extract digits after 'ID' occurrence in the following text
This is how I am able to get it.

```
import re

txt="Recharge done on 28-12-2017 04:57PM,MRP:Rs9.00,GST 18% payable by Company/Distributor/Retailer:Rs1.37, ID 147894886."

# 'ID' need to be present as mandatory group
regex = '(id)(.*?)(\d+})' 

rg = re.compile(regex ,re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
m = rg.search(txt)
if m:
    print m.group(3)
```

When I run the following code, it prints

```
147894886
```

Here comes the problem

If txt become like this

```
txt="Recharge done on 28-12-2017 04:57PM,MRP:Rs9.00,GST 18% payable by Company/Distributor/Retailer:Rs1.37, TransID 147894886."
```

and "Trans" word appears before "ID" then I dont want to extract digits. How to do that in regex (i.e don't extract digits if "TransID" is present before digits but only if "ID" is present then extract digits)

Comment: Are you specifically looking for `trans` or do you want to ensure, that `id` is a whole word. If the later, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751301/regex-match-entire-words-only

Comment: I want to ensure that characters before ID should not be '(trans|trx|transc)' etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookbehind [[doc](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)] :

```
(?<!trans)(id)(.*?)(\d+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/n8q5X1/1)

Or, as Sebastian Proske suggests, you can use a word boundary :

```
\b(id)(.*?)(\d+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/n8q5X1/2)

Comment: What if i want to use this regex ->>>     (?<!trans|transaction|trx|tranc|transc)(id|account|landline|fixedline|towards|dsl|a\/c|ca|no|number)(.*?)(\d{6,12}) this is giving error as  error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern

Comment: If multiple possibilities for negative lookbehind are there eg. transacid OR transid OR trxid then also it should not match and return group

Comment: You can separate the excluded strings in several negative lookbehind groups : [like here](https://regex101.com/r/n8q5X1/3)

Comment: Worked like a charm. I didn't knew that it can be done like that. Thanks a lot ! Cheers  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a word boundary (`\b`) to make sure that `ID` is a full word.

```
\b(id)(.*?)(\d+)
```

It might also help to match your pattern less generally. If you always have `ID` followed by a space, followed by 9 numbers, you can use this regex:

```
\b(id)([ ])(\d{9})
```

[Pythex Demo](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5Cb(id)(%5B%20%5D)(%5Cd%7B9%7D)&test_string=Recharge%20done%20on%2028-12-2017%2004%3A57PM%2CMRP%3ARs9.00%2CGST%2018%25%20payable%20by%20Company%2FDistributor%2FRetailer%3ARs1.37%2C%20ID%20147894886.%0ARecharge%20done%20on%2028-12-2017%2004%3A57PM%2CMRP%3ARs9.00%2CGST%2018%25%20payable%20by%20Company%2FDistributor%2FRetailer%3ARs1.37%2C%20TransID%20147894886.&ignorecase=1&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)