# RegEx letter but not part of a word

Tags: regex, kotlin

I've the below code that is answering the `where are you` regex, this could be `w r u` and so.

I I entered `how r u`, the regex will understand it as `w r u`, which is not correct in real, how to fix it?

```
val regEx = """((where|were|w)\s*(are|r)\s*(you|u)(?-i))""".toRegex()

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val matchResult = regEx.find("how r u")
    println("Hello, world!: ${matchResult?.value.orEmpty()}")
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output for `how r u`?

Comment: If it is not correct so what is the correct form? You didn't consider word *how* in  your regex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex match entire words only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751301/regex-match-entire-words-only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

`(^|\s+)`

You can use the beginning of line `^` char to achieve a better matcher. If you combine it with a whitespace matcher like this `(^|\s+)` you make sure you only get the words `(where|were|w)`

```
(^|\s+)(where|were|w)\s*(are|r)\s*(you|u)(?-i)
```

or

```
(^|\s+)(where|were|w)\s*(are|r)\s*(you|u)\s+(?-i)
```

see https://regex101.com/r/xyjrO4/1

**Option 2**

`\b`

Use the word boundary `\b` see [java regex boundaries](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html)

```
\b(where|were|w)\s*(are|r)\s*(you|u)(?-i)
```

taking it to the full extend would be

```
\b(where|were|w)\b\s*\b(are|r)\b\s*\b(you|u)\b(?-i)
```

(which wouldnt match "wru" though)

Or

```
((where|were|\bw)\s*(are|r)\s*(you|u)(?-i))
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not a must to to be beginning of the line, could be `hi w r u`

Comment: in that case add a group that catches space characters or line beginnings -> see the update