# Split regex in to two regex: whole words only & words with substring matches only

Tags: php, regex

I have below code that removes whole words that contain any pattern

```
$patterns = ["are", "finite", "get", "er"];
$string = "You are definitely getting better today";

$re = '\S*('.implode('|', $patterns).')\S*';
$string = preg_replace('#'.$re.'#', '', $string);
$string = preg_replace('#\h{2,}#', ' ', $string);
echo $string;
```

the output of the above code is

```
You today
```

I want to split this code into two functions so that the first function only removes whole words present in the pattern and a second function that only removes words that contain any pattern.

I expect the output of the function one that remove only whole words

```
You definitely getting better today (**are** is removed)
```

and output of the other function that remove whole word that contain pattern

```
You are today (**definitely getting better** are removed)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part is basic: Only match whole keywords (actually, you can find dozens of Q&As like that, e.g [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751301/regex-match-entire-words-only))

```
\b(?:are|finite|get|er)\b
```

Which can be applied to your code like this: `$re = '\b('.implode('|', $patterns).')\b';`

The second part is a bit more involved: While you keep expanding substring matches to match the entire word you want to exclude words that match whole keywords.
We can use a lookahead to achieve this like that:

```
(?!\b(?:are|finite|get|er)\b)\S*(?:are|finite|get|er)\S*
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/wPEKUw/1), 
[Sample Code](https://ideone.com/Klypi7):

```
$patterns = ["are", "finite", "get", "er"];
$string = "You are definitely getting better today";
$alternations = ''.implode('|', $patterns);
$re = '(?!\b(?:'.$alternations.')\b)\S*(?:'.$alternations.')\S*';
$string = preg_replace('#'.$re.'#', '', $string);
```

---

If the \b does not work for you and you'd like to go with space as word boundary use [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<=\s)(?:are|finite|get|er)(?=\s)
```

[Sample Code](https://ideone.com/D9iMyp) (updated) case 1.

Comment: Thank you very much @wp78de