# How to match the beginning of a partial or a whole word anywhere in a string for the given pattern?

Tags: regex

Sentence = I will buy a red car, a black racecar or a blue caravan

Pattern = *car*

Result: should match `car` and `caravan` (partial or whole word anywhere in the sentence). Should not match `racecar` (not the beginning of a word)

Edit: This question is not a duplicate of [Regex match entire words only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1751301/1800515) because that question specifically asks NOT to match partial words. My requirement is to match partial OR whole words.

Comment: You should always look for some [quick reference guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) if you are not an expert (like me).

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado: This is a reference for .NET only. A better reference is https://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: @CertainPerformance  This question is not a duplicate of Regex match entire words only because that question specifically asks NOT to match partial words. My requirement is to match partial OR whole words.

Comment: The principle is exactly the same. To check identify the boundary between a word character and a non-word character, use a word boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a wordboundary at the beginning:

```
\bcar\w*
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/H3NF2B/1)