# New line break every two words in javascript string

Tags: javascript

I have one string

```
string = "example string is cool and you're great for helping out"
```

I want to insert a line break every two words so it returns this:

```
string = 'example string \n
is cool  \n
and you're  \n
great for \n
helping out'
```

I am working with variables and cannot manually do this. I need a function that can take this string and handle it for me.

Thanks!!

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: I've been looking into concat options and I know that js6 makes it pretty easy to add in line breaks with back ticks. The problem is I have no idea how to tell my function to add it in every two words.

Comment: starting point to match a word https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751301/regex-match-entire-words-only

Answer (score 6):

You can use replace method of string.

```
   (.*?\s.*?\s)
```

- `.*?`- Match anything except new line. lazy mode.
- `\s` - Match a space character.

```js
let string = "example string is cool and you're great for helping out" 

console.log(string.replace(/(.*?\s.*?\s)/g, '$1'+'\n'))
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use this regular expression: `(\S+\s*){1,2}`:

```js
var string = "example string is cool and you're great for helping out";
var result = string.replace(/(\S+\s*){1,2}/g, "$&\n");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: +1. Appears to correctly add a new line after every second word, and not every second white space as appears in the most up-voted answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, split the list into an array `array = str.split(" ")` and initialize an empty string `var newstring = ""`. Now, loop through all of the array items and add everything back into the string with the line breaks `array.forEach(function(e, i) {newstring += e + " "; if((i + 1) % 2 = 0) {newstring += "\n "};})`
In the end, you should have:

```
array = str.split(" ");
var newstring = "";
array.forEach(function(e, i) {
    newstring += e + " "; 
    if((i + 1) % 2 = 0) {
        newstring += "\n ";
    }
})
```

`newstring` is the string with the line breaks!

Answer (score 1):

```
let str = "example string is cool and you're great for helping out" ;

function everyTwo(str){
    return str
        .split(" ") // find spaces and make array from string
        .map((item, idx) => idx % 2 === 0 ? item : item + "\n") // add line break to every second word
        .join(" ") // make string from array
}

console.log(
    everyTwo(str)
)

output => example string
 is cool
 and you're
 great for
 helping out
```