# gsub all instances of substring once

Tags: ruby, gsub

My goal is to replace all instances of the substring **"test_"** to **"append.test_"**. This can occur multiple times in a sentence. For example:

*I am test_a and test_b* => *I am append.test_a and append.test_b*

The problem is that I can have something like this

*I am test_a and I am test_b_test_c*

I can't figure out the right regex because when I try to use
`my_string.gsub('test_', "append.test_")` it returns

> I am append.test_a and I am append.test_b_append.test_c

My expected result:

> I am append.test_a and I am append.test_b_test_c

Any ideas?

Comment: Your question is incomplete. What is the desired result for the string, `"test_a test_ test_1 test_@ attest_c :test_d"`? The problem is that you are expressing the question in terms of a couple of examples. That is rarely sufficient for a question to be precise and unambiguous. You need to state your question in words and then use examples merely for illustration. You may find that difficult but it is a skill you need to master to prepare specifications for computer programs.

Comment: The tag "string" is redundant since you have "regex". I think I'd probably just have "ruby" and "regex" but I suppose a case could be made that someone may also use "gsub" in a search.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex match entire words only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751301/regex-match-entire-words-only)

Comment: There are several reasons to wait at least a few hours before selecting an answer. There's no rush.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you wish to avoid replacing in situations where nothing else precedes `test_` in a string, you can use `\b` to check for a word boundary before `test_`.

```rb
s = "I am test_a and I am test_b_test_c"

s.gsub(/\btest_/, "append.test_")
# => "I am append.test_a and I am append.test_b_test_c"
```