# To count and display “No. of times” of presence of words “the” and “to” in a string. (should not count words like these and top)

Tags: python, string, loops, count

**Problem Detail**

I am stuck in this... I can calculate the number of times "the" and "to" will occur by using the count function but it will also include the occurrence in these and top which is not needed so how should I approach this question?
I only know basic operators, Loops, Str Functions, etc

**What I Tried**

I thought that the exact occurrence would be having " " in its T[EndChar+1] But how will I get the index of ending char where it is occurring

```
 N=input("")
print(N.count("the"))
# Input: these are the boxes
# Output: 2
# Expected Output: 1
# As I want the occurrence of "the" not "the" in "these"
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please show us your attempt!

Comment: I have edited see

Comment: If you are fine with using regular expressions for the task, consider this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751301/regex-match-entire-words-only

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You want the number of occurrences of 'the' and 'to' in a string if I understood correctly.

```py
#input
s = "These To The Top"

#split the string when space occurs -> s = ["These","To","The","Top"]

t = list(s.split(" "))

#filter when it equals to "The" or "To"
q = filter(lambda x:x == "The" or x == "To",t)

#join list as string
a = list(q).join(' ')

a.count("The")
a.count("To")
```

Or you can use regex

Comment: He is looking for the number of times two specific words occur. You only need to calculate the number of occurrences, not return a new list.

Comment: Now my answer shows the number of occurrences