# Detecting a specific word in a message in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I tried the 2 solutions posted here to detect a specific words and they do work:

**Solution 1**

```
const badMessages = ["bad", "worst"];
badMessages.forEach((word) => {
if (message.content.includes(word)) {
message.reply("Detected.");
}
})
```

**Solution 2**

```
const badMessages = ["bad", "worst"];
for(var i=0; i<badMessages.length; i++) {
if (message.content.includes(badMessages[i])) {
message.reply("Detected.");
}
}
```

However, the condition triggers even when the word in the array for example **bad** is mixed with other words like **"badge"**. How do I detect a specific word by itself which should trigger for the exact "bad" word only and not trigger when it is mixed with other words like badge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the regular expression `\b(bad|wrong)\b`
https://regex101.com/r/cxHSki/1

```js
const messages = [
    'bad bads man wrong',
    'bads man wrong',
    'abad man wrong',
    'abad man wrongs',
    'abad man awrong',
    'bad man',
    'wrong man',
    'badge text'
]
const badMessages = ["bad","wrong"];

messages.forEach(x => {
  const regex = RegExp(`(\\b)(${badMessages.join('|')})(\\b)`, 'g')
  //const regex = RegExp(`(\\b)(${badMessages.join('|')})(\\b)`, 'gi') for case insensitive 
  const isMatch = regex.test(x)
  console.log(isMatch)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to wrap all bad words with spaces, so it will only search for those specific words separated by spaces?

Better solution would be to use a regular expression like what has been suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751301/regex-match-entire-words-only).